# inheritance many tables doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

Consider these entities:

Person

Student

Employee

I have three tables representing each entity. Person stores the data in common. Child tables have a primary key which is a foreign key for person.

In doctrine the inheritance option forces the creation of a field in the parent entity, to say who its child is. This is not good. This may not be the best example, but I could have a student who is an employee.

what approach would be interesting to solve this problem. one to one? How could I create a person transparently, through a student, for example?

**update 1**

[mapping Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I8Pd.png)

[mapping Student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul0m5.png)

[mapping Contracting Company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytwcv.png)

[repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbiyW.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn3T6.png)

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDUcr.png)

It worked. I'll do the job of instantiating that person and passing it on to your child. I wanted to make this more transparent, without needing to instantiate person outside of student, for example.

I will have other entities related to people with their specific characteristics

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep just one entity: Person. If a Person has an occupation is Employee. If a person is subscribed somewhere could be a student. And can be also a student and an employee whenever the person has jobs and is subscribe in some courses.

Comment: I will have many fields on the child entities and many child entities. Unify in person, it would be a very large table

Comment: I never talked about unification. I just talked about one person entity. I'll add ManyToMany relations to other entities. What differs a person from an employee (for example)? An employee is a person with a job. So, ... You'll have an entity person related manytomany to some jobs. A Person that have one or more jobs is an Employee.

Comment: I have specific data for person, institution, student, isolated in their tables

Comment: Ok, ... please, ... update question with doctrine entities.

Comment: I updated the question